# Count nonzero elements and plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to count the number of nonzero elements in the list below-
[image]

I tried this code,

```
nzcnt = [nonzero.count(0),nonzero.count(1),nonzero.count(2),nonzero.count(3),nonzero.count(4),nonzero.count(5),nonzero.count(6),nonzero.count(7),nonzero.count(8),nonzero.count(9)]
```

But it is not really *pythonic*. How can I change this more *pythonic*?

NOTE: allowed library : `numpy`, `pandas`, `matplotlib`, `copy`

Comment: You can use `np.count_nonzero(df, axis=0)` for column-wise number of non-zero elements. Or `df.astype(bool).sum(axis=0)`. Can you show how you plan to plot it?

Comment: np.sum(w_check!=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.count_nonzero(DATAFRAME, axis=0)` will help you to find the nonzero elements through the column.

And of course the plot is done by `plt.plot`!

Answer (score 1):

You can  flatten the list and then count the number of zeros. You can use `w_check.flatten()` for that.